# Cannot understand Java class definition

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a problem with some Java coding. I saw this coding while I'm studying Java and cannot understand it...
Below are some examples:

```
public class interface Set<E>

public class SocreManager extends ValueSortedMap<String,Integer>
```

The things that i cannot understand is the things inside the <> (in this example E and String,Integer )
What this <> mean?
I Googled and I still cannot find a answer.

Comment: Google asking for **genercis**

Comment: This is not legal syntax. Post the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassA<ClassB>` Stands for `ClassA` that is using *generics* - one of java features

`public class interface Set`

this means that `Set` will be somewhat related to some other type (`E`). Set is holder for some objects. If you declare it as `Set<String>` you can put there only Strings, or something casted to String. That's the use of `<E>` here.

`public class SocreManager extends ValueSortedMap`

SocreManager is wrapper for `ValueSortedMap` it can add some new methods to `ValueSortedMap` but it also can add noting to it, and be used only as class name beautifier. If you add none features to SocreManager, than you will have everything the same as in `ValueSortedMap` but with shorter and simpler name - `SocreManager`. But looking at this name tells me that I will contain something more then just methods from super class.